# How do I delete all .txt files in a directory

Tags: c#

Look At This Code :

```
private void confirmBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] filePaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\", "*.txt");
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {

        if (filePath.EndsWith(".txt")) return;

        MessageBox.Show("Delete All Text Files?", "Delete Verification"
      , MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
        }
    }
```

I want to create a program which will delete all the .txt files in a specific directory and will create buttons of Yes or No and when clicked Yes = Delete When No = Abort.

Comment: What is wrong with it at the moment? (apart from it not compiling)

Comment: `if (filePath.EndsWith(".txt")) return;` You want to delete *.txt-files, then why are you exiting your method before you can delete them? :)

Comment: Please remember that your question should always also be a help for future visitors. The title of your question will be used for search engines. Also, don't append the language to your title, it's already tagged.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 2):

Ask the question before entering the loop, and there is no need to check the extension because you have already asked to return only the files with the TXT extension 
By the way the test for

```
if (filePath.EndsWith(".txt")) return;
```

is the reason that blocks the deleting of any file in your original code (and asking the same question over and over)

```
    if(MessageBox.Show("Delete All Text Files?", "Delete Verification"
      , MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        string[] filePaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\", "*.txt");
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)

            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
```

Comment: Groan, do you really have to encourage such bad questions by giving them a full solution

Comment: @musefan I agree on the relative value of the question, but it respects all the rules of the site. There is a problem and there is a wrong code so I provide an answer.

Comment: But the OP hasn't even said what is wrong with the code. Maybe they want a `MessageBox` for each file, for example. Rather than making such assumptions, I believe the OP should be encourage to improve their question. But now, we just have another one time user who will never learn, they will be back next week with a brand new account and still asking bad questions

Comment: I know my comment is unsolicited and I'm nobody to say anything. But I do salute both of you for your points. I know how hard it is to start programming, so Steve has done a great help. On the other hand, musefan does have a point too. I remember I once asked a master programmer and all he gave me was, that's easy, google it. I was so mad because nobody wanted to help me. So I started learning on my own. But @Steve, you have my RESPECT sir. I know what it's like to be ignored :)

Comment: @chris_techno25 keep the good attitude toward learning on your own and you will have a treasure in your hand before you realize it.

Comment: @Steve, Thank you Sir. We don't know each other but what you said means a lot to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your condition check is not valid:.

first condition should be:

```
if (!filePath.EndsWith(".txt")) return;
```

and second:

```
 DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Delete All Text Files?", "Delete Verification", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
 if( res == DialogResult.Yes)
 {
    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are returning when txt file is found. Whereas it should be other way around.

```
if (filePath.EndsWith(".txt")) 
    return;
```

should be

```
if (!filePath.EndsWith(".txt")) 
    return;
```

This should do it

```
string directoryPath = @"C:\test\";
string extension = "*.txt";
if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            return;

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(extension).Where(p => p.Extension.ToLowerInvariant() == ".txt").ToArray();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
      file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
      File.Delete(file.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Will `p.Extension` every return `"*.txt"`?

Comment: It won't let me remove vote, it doesn't realise there has been an edit, and says "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"

Answer (score -1):

You have to put the question outside the loop. Your code would execute the MessageBox for every file it sees which contradicts to your question "Delete All Text Files?".

Comment: I know who commented. If it was a syntax error, please do keep in mind that it should be pointed out. If I did anything wrong, I stand corrected, I apologize.

Comment: Point taken. My bad, I just thought I'd continue the thread. So sorry for that. I'll delete the comment sir.

Comment: First off thanks for the help and I'll fix my next question more organized way.
Secondly people like this encourages people like me to continue to learn and when someone else feel a problem I can solve I'd love to help.

By the way how can I register a private message to man helped me and save unnecessary talk?

Comment: Kudos to your effort my friend. We're on the same boat here because we still have a lot to learn. Don't mind the downvotes. I got a lot of downvotes. Downvotes don't mean your question is bad, it just means you need more effort to search for the solution before posting the question. This is coming from someone who learned programming on his own.

Comment: @user3172547: You don't thank people privately. If an answer has solved the problem for you then you should accept that answer by clicking the tick icon to the left hand side. [See here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)